# Flask - Set cookies using List

Tags: python, flask, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie which equals to a List using Flask

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
resp = make_response(render_template('home.html'))
cookiePayload = [userName, rights]
resp.set_cookie('username', cookiePayload)
return resp
```

But it throws me some TypeError. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the documentation of the `set_cookie` method:

> Sets a cookie. The parameters are the same as in the cookie Morsel object in the Python standard library but it accepts unicode data, too.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response.set_cookie

So, you need to convert these list into a string. One of the ways to achieve that is to convert list into json object.

Lets see in action

```
import json


resp = make_response(render_template('home.html'))
cookiePayload = [userName, rights]
resp.set_cookie('username', json.dumps(cookiePayload))
return resp
```

Comment: Thanks! that works. But now when I get the cookie it returns me this `"["myusername"\054 "False"]"`. I can't seem to index it properly. if i do `[0]` it returns me `[`

Comment: To use this cookie, you have to load it. Still using `json`, you can do `json.loads(you_cookie_var)` and then you can access it as array.